# Add a sub-menu to a pre-existing navigation with CSS

Tags: css, navigation, submenu

I have a pre-existing responsive menu but I need to add a sub-navigation for each menu choice. How can I do this with CSS?

The important code, I think, is in the section *primary navigation*.

Thank you in advance for everyone that can help me to understand how sub-menus work.

```css
/** 
/* 06. =header styles
/* =================================================================== */

html,
body {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 background: #0F1215;
 font: 16px/30px "merriweather-regular", serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #575859;
}


header {
 height: 66px;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 600;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;  

 
}
header.opaque {
 background: black;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

/* header logo */
header .logo {
 background: #fdc501;
 float: left;
 width: auto;
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 z-index: 600;    
 
 /* add position relative since z-index only applies to  
 elements that have been given an explicit position */
 position: relative;
}

header .logo a {
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 font: 0/0 a;
 text-shadow: none;
 color: transparent;
 width: 114px;
 height: 66px;
 background: url("../images/logoK@2x.png") no-repeat center;
 background-size: 61px 14px;
}

/* header social */
header .header-social {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: 66px;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-left: 30px;
 padding-left: 36px;
 border-left: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.2);
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 top: -1px;
}

header .header-social li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 15px;
}

header .header-social li a {
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

header .header-social li a:hover {
 color: #fdc501;
}

/* media queries:  
/* header/header components */
@media only screen and (max-width:880px) {
 header .header-social {
  display: none;
 }

}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
 header {
  background: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
 }

 header .row {
  width: 100%;
 }

 header .logo {
  margin-left: -30px;
 }

}

/* primary navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#nav-wrap,
#nav-wrap ul,
#nav-wrap li,
#nav-wrap a {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/* nav-wrap */
#nav-wrap {
 font: 13px "raleway-heavy", sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1.5px;
 float: left;  
}

/* hide toggle button */
#nav-wrap > a {
 display: none;
}

ul#nav {
 min-height: 66px;
 display: inline-block;
 width: auto;  

 /* left align the menu */
 text-align: left;
}

ul#nav li {
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 66px;    
}

/* Links */
ul#nav li a {

 /* 14px padding top + 14px padding bottom + 38px line-height = 66px */
 display: block;
 padding: 14px 12px;
 line-height: 38px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: left;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 position: relative;
 -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

ul#nav li a:hover {
 color: #fdc501;
}

ul#nav li a:active {
 background-color: transparent !important;
}

ul#nav li.current a {
 color: #fdc501;
}

ul#nav li.current a:after {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 40px;
 height: 2px;
 margin-left: -23px;
 background-color: white;
 content: '\0020';
 display: block;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

/* mobile navigation 
--------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
 #nav-wrap {
  z-index: 700;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
 }

 /* mobile-btn and toggle-btn */
 #nav-wrap > a {
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
  right: 20px;
 }

 #nav-wrap > a:hover .menu-icon {
  background: #FFFFFF;
 }

 #nav-wrap .menu-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  background: #fdc501;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  font: 0/0 a;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: transparent;
 }

 #nav-wrap .menu-icon:before,
 #nav-wrap .menu-icon:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: inherit;
  left: 0;
 }

 #nav-wrap .menu-icon:before {
  bottom: 8px;
 }

 #nav-wrap .menu-icon:after {
  top: 8px;
 }

 /* dropdown nav */
 #nav-wrap ul#nav {
  background: #1c212a;
  padding: 54px 45px 60px 45px;
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 66px;
  right: 0;
 }

 #nav-wrap ul#nav > li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  height: auto;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.1);
  padding: 6px 0;
 }

 #nav-wrap ul#nav > li:first-child {
  border-top: 1px dotted rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.1);
 }

 #nav-wrap ul#nav li a {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  color: #cacbcb;
  padding: 12px 0;
  line-height: 16px;
  border: none;
 }

 #nav-wrap ul#nav li a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
 }

 #nav-wrap ul#nav li.current > a {
  background: none;
  color: #fdc501;
 }

 #nav-wrap ul#nav li.current > a:after {
  display: none;
 }

 #nav-wrap a.mobile-btn {
  display: none;
 }

 .js #nav-wrap a#toggle-btn {
  display: block;
 }

 /* if js is disabled */
 .no-js #nav-wrap:not(:target) > a:first-of-type,
 .no-js #nav-wrap:target > a:last-of-type {
  display: block;
 }

 .no-js #nav-wrap:target ul#nav {
  display: block;
 }

}

/* make sure the menu is visible on larger screens
--------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media only screen and (min-width:769px) {
 #nav-wrap ul#nav {
  display: block !important;
 }

}
```

```html
 <header id="main-header">

    <div class="row">

       <div class="logo">
          <a href="index.html">SAT | Aloia Evelina</a>
       </div>

       <nav id="nav-wrap">         
          
          <a class="mobile-btn" href="#nav-wrap" title="Show navigation">
           <span class="menu-icon">Menu</span>
          </a>
          <a class="mobile-btn" href="#" title="Hide navigation">
           <span class="menu-icon">Menu</span>
          </a>            

          <ul id="nav" class="nav">
             <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#hero">Home.</a></li>
           <li class="current"><a class="smoothscroll" href="#portfolio">Works.</a></li>
             <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#services">Services.</a></li>
             <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#about">About.</a></li>
             <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#contact">Contact.</a></li>
          </ul> <!-- end #nav -->

       </nav> <!-- end #nav-wrap -->

       <ul class="header-social">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
       </ul>      

    </div>

   </header> <!-- end header -->
```

Comment: Im working too on it, if i find the answer i will auto-response to myself XD

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="nav" class="nav">
<li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#hero">Home.</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">#item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">#item1</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="current"><a class="smoothscroll" href="#portfolio">Works.</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">#item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">#item1</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#services">Services.</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">#item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">#item1</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#about">About.</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">#item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">#item1</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#contact">Contact.</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">#item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">#item1</a></li>
    </ul>
</li> </ul>
```

in your html file you code should look something like this.

and then for more details on how you can style your code you can visit the site https://css-tricks.com/targetting-menu-elements-submenus-navigation-bar/

It provides some tricks in which you can style your menu as well as I how the html file should look like. I find it very much helpfull.